# Get the error returned by FFMPEG

Tags: php, error-handling, ffmpeg

How do I know there is error occured in ffmpeg command? and How do I get the error in my php?

below is my code

```
    <?php
      $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $vid -an -ss $getfromsecond -s $size -vframes 1 $imageFile";

       if(!shell_exec($cmd)){
         echo "Thumbnail created" . "<br/>";
       }else{
          echo "Error Creating thumbnail". "<br/>";
        }
    ?>
```

I am not sure if above approach is right.I have also tried below code

```
exec($cmd, $output, $return);
echo '$output :' ; print_r($output); echo "<br/>";echo '$return :' . $return . "<br/>";exit;
```

but in server it is just showing out put as

```
$output :Array ( ) 
$return127
```

I don't understand what is that error no, How to know if error has occurred and return the `ffmpeg` error no and `ffmpeg` error text , in php.

Answer (score 1):

use it

```
exec($cmd,$test);
```

then check

```
if(file_exists($image))
{
echo 'suc';
}
```

Comment: but this is custom error I want the error returned by `ffmpeg`

Comment: Thanks @Ranjeet Singh , but All I saw was `error no` not `error text`. If error is returned by exec function by default , how to print those errors

Comment: in my test if something goes wrong then i received error in array

Comment: hmm, So `$output = exec($cmd,$test);` is giving you an array and if there is error `$output` will have  `error array` AM I RIGHT?